# Calculating a specific distance from points along a network - GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, network-analysis

[image]
I'm currently using the v.net.iso function in GRASS (no access to network analyst in ArcMap). Does anybody know of a way to export the result to shapefile so that you have an individual line feature(s) for each point?
Currently, one can only see what areas along the network that are within that specific distance from the nearest point as opposed to being able to select an actual line segment of specified distance from each point.

The current result does not show you an actual specified distance path, but rather where along the network a segment of the network falls within that distance (difficult when there are overlaps - no way of seeing where these distances actually fall).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this 240m value?

Comment: Oh, the 240m is arbitrary.  I'm basically interested in calculating separate lines along the road network that when overlapped do not merge.  For instance, if two points along a path are 300m apart, and I want to calculate a 200m distance from each, how can I get two separate lines that overlap instead of one merged line?  Currently in GRASS, the result when exporting to shapefile will be one single line between the two points (which is correct in that every point between the two points I'm measuring from is within 200m of the nearest stop - I just can't tell where that 200m point actually is)